# Sufficient conditions for a set to be a countable generator of a metrizable topology

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis, metric-spaces

Let $(\Omega, \tau)$ be a metrizable topological space and $A$ be a countable, dense subset.

Just a question on the logic of proving that a set, say $\mathcal{E}:=\{B_{q}(a):a \in A, q \in \mathbb Q_{+}\}$ is a countable generator of $\Omega$.

I thought: We let a $B \in \tau$ and need to find a cover $(A_{n})_{n}\subseteq \tau$, so that $\bigcup\limits_{n \in \mathbb N} A_{n}=B$

But can I rather prove it by looking at individual elements of $\Omega$? i.e. Let $\omega\in \Omega$ arbitrary and then for any $B_{r}(\omega)$ if we can find a $q \in \mathbb Q_{+}$ and an $a \in A$ such that $B_{q}(a)\subseteq B_{r}(\omega)$ then we are done? Am I correct? I am just unsure whether this condition is enough because I am not sure whether the union then remains countable?

I just need a logic refresher.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is enough. If for every $x \in B_r(\omega)$ you show that there are $a_x \in A$ and $q_x \in \mathbb{Q}_+$ such that $x \in B_{q_x}(a_x)\subset B_r(\omega)$, then of course $B_r(\omega)$ is the union of the family $\{ B_{q_x}(a_x)\}_{x \in B_r(\omega)}$. Why is this family countable? Well, because it is a subfamily of the family $\mathcal{E}$, which is countable.

The family $\mathcal{E}$ is countable because $\mathcal{E}=\bigcup_{a \in A}\{B_q(a):q\in \mathbb{Q}_+\}$, where $A$ is countable and, for every $a\in A$, it is the case that $\{B_q(a):q\in \mathbb{Q}_+\}$ is countable. Hence, if $\{a_n \}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is an enumeration of $A$, the map: $$\mathcal{E} \ni B_q(a_n)\mapsto (n,q)\in \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{Q}_+$$ is injective, and of course $\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{Q}_+$ is countable.

Answer (score 1):

It's enough to note that the set $\mathcal{E}$ is countable (it's indexed by the countable set $A \times \Bbb Q^+$) and that it is a base for the topology $\tau$.

And the latter indeed means

$$\forall O \in \tau: \forall \omega \in O: \exists E \in \mathcal{E}: \omega \in E \subseteq O\tag{1}$$

And this can easily be seen: first pick $r>0$ such that $B_r(\omega) \subseteq O$ by openness of $O$ in the metric topology. Also, find $a \in B_{\frac{r}{2}}(\omega)$ by density of $A$, and find a rational $q>0$ such that $d(a,\omega) < q < \frac{r}{2}$. Then $x \in B_q(a)$ implies

$$d(x,\omega) \le d(x,a) + d(a,\omega) < q + \frac{r}{2} < r$$

so that $$\omega \in B_q(a) \subseteq B_r(\omega) \subseteq O$$

as required, as $B_q(a) \in \mathcal{E}$.

$(1)$ implies that we can write any subset open $O$ as a union of elements from $\mathcal{E}$ and this union is automatically countable as $\mathcal{E}$ is (we will use many elements of $\mathcal{E}$ doubly in general, but in a set repeated elements don't matter). Or given $O$ in $\tau$, we define $$\mathcal{E}(O) = \{E \in \mathcal{E}: E \subseteq O\}$$

and then $(1)$ says that $O \subseteq \bigcup \mathcal{E}(O)$ and the reverse inclusion is clear from the definition (a union of subsets of $O$ is a subet of $O$) so

$$\bigcup \mathcal{E}(O) = O$$

as required, and $\mathcal{E}(O) \subseteq \mathcal{E}$ is of course countable.